# Problem while embedding code in Contentful CMS

Tags: reactjs, content-management-system, gatsby, contentful

I have a problem in generating a blog posts through CONTENTFUL CMS. I tried to embed code, but in my live server all my code is showing in single line.

Selected all my code and clicked on CODE in toolbar. It changed the font of the code that I embedded.
But in my server it is showing like all my code in single line.

Attached the screenshots below for your reference.

[image: Screenshot of Added Code in Contentful-preview]

[image: Screenshot of Live-preview in my browser]

Can you guys help me to sort out this.

Comment: please post the code as a script, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Rich Text` for your `Blog Post` model.  You can create an additional content model using `Long Text` to host source codes and embed your source code model in your `Blog Post`.

For `Long Text`, you will be able to use markdown syntax. So you can do something like the following to preserve the format.

````
```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'gatsby';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';
import Head from '../components/Head';

const AboutPage = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Layout>
        <Head title="About" />
        <h1>About Me</h1>
        <p>I'm a Engineer.</p>
        <p><Link to="/contact">Want to work with me? React out.</Link></p>
      </Layout>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AboutPage;

```
````

I hope it helps.

---

**Updates:**

I think this listing the steps can make the answer more clear to follow.

1. Create a new model called `Code Block` using `Long Text` type.
2. Create a new `Code Block` which has your source code.
3. In you body section, `Embed` -> `Inline entry` -> Select the `Code Block` content you just created.

Comment: so you are saying that, for the body section in contentful its better to add "Text" format rather than "Rich Text" which i added currently. then i can add the code like ... ```   ```

Comment: @buttlerwk You will keep using `Rich Text`. I added the steps to make my answer a bit more clear to follow, hopefully.